# get current user from word add-in sharepoint

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, office-integration

How can i get the current user that loaded a file from a sharepoint library?

When I load a file from a doc library on sharepoint, Word prompts me a window to type my UserName and Password to connect to the sharepoint site.

How can I get this username on the add-in or on the server side?

I've beem trying to use on the server side using:

```
SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
```

I tought that was going to solve my problems, but it seems to get always the same user, it doesn't matter which one I log-in on the MSWord prompt or on the Sharepoint Site for some reason.

Does anyone know what might be the solution?

Comment: `SPContext` will work only if the code is executed in SharePoint server. In case of office its a client application and used SharePoint web service to communicate.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a webmethod to access the server, and the server is using SPContext..

Comment: Are you suggesting, you created a webservice that is hosted on SharePoint? And you are trying to access that web method from Office?

Comment: I can access any of the webMethods I did, I just cannot get the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to get the username and password (or the token) that the user has provided to Word or any office application.

This will be a risk if such a way exist in the first place.

For the current user (the user who logged into the system) you can invoke the webservice and pass the network credentials as

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://tempuri.org/");
ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");
```

Another option is to create your own form and request the user for credentials so You can cache it somewhere and use it for communication with SharePoint

Comment: This won't work for me, because I need the user who opened the file from sharepoint on the first place, not the user on the system.

Comment: @smith then your only option is to create a custom login form and get it from the user.